# Getting STDOUT in iOS from PHP script

Tags: php, ios, swift

I have a PHP script that executes a local command and prints and flushes the stdout. For example, it would print something like

```
1
```

and then after a second

```
1 2
```

and then after a second

```
1 2 3
```

So on and so forth. I want to be able to get that data as it comes in iOS. I found this function but it does not return anything until the page fully loads:

```
@IBAction func doButton (sender:AnyObject!) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://mywebsite.local/script.php")!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Any ideas on how I can flush the data as it comes?

Comment: Have you considered establishing a websocket connection with the server?

Comment: PHP and/or your HTTP server are probably buffering the connection, look into that. But using a websocket is probably a better solution than holding open an HTTP connection, which may incur additional problems.